# I have a text file containing Multiple line text and need to compare this text with the text in web application using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I have a Word file containing Multiple line text which include bullet points, headings and need to compare this text with the text in web application. Is it possible to do using UFT ?

Comment: so is it a word document or a text file?

Comment: It is a word document.